# Unit testing Internet connectivity in Xamarin Forms

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms

```
public class InternetConnection : IInternetConnection
{
    public async Task<bool> CheckInternetStatusAsync()
    {
        if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            //delay to check handle network blips in restaurants
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

How do i Unit test Internet Connectivity in xamarin forms ?
UnitTesting using NUnit.

Comment: I don't think internet connectivity is something that should be unit tested.

Comment: Then How will I test this method which is in my View Model: `private async Task<bool> CheckDataConfig()
        {
            try
            {
                if (await _internetConnection.CheckInternetStatusAsync())
                {
                    // Functionality
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Exception
            }
            return false;
        }`

Comment: You need to mock the call to the method.

Answer (score 1):

How Andrew says, Internet connectivity it's not be tested with Unit Test, it's part of End to End Test. Unit test must check the behavior of your piece of code (without any interaction of another externals components like database, services or Internet) with mocking data and with the "What if" scenario: What if the service return null object, What if the service return a empty list, What if the service return a expected list of objects, etc. All these escenarios should be covered by your piece of code to avoid crashes or unexpected behaviors. more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2022)

[image]